# MySQL After Update and After Insert Triggers fail when row is entered

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I need to create a MySQL trigger that multiplies the values of two columns in one table and saves that result in the column of another table. I have a table called lineitems that gets the product dimensions entered into it. I need to multiply the height and width of each lineitem row and add them together if they are part of the same order number and save that result in a sqft column of a table called invoices. I need this to happen every time the lineitems table gets a new row or an existing row is updated. I also need to do a very similar process for the item quantity of each lineitem row. And last, I need to do a third calculation where the weight of each product is calculated and stored in the lineitems table. However, that weight calculation involves a third table (layup_config) to derive the weight for only the layers used in the specific product ordered.

Code:

I have tried setting this trigger up both on the invoices table AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE as well as on the lineitems table AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE. However, I would prefer that this happens in the lineitems table if possible.

Note: I am using phpmyadmin to access and manipulate my table triggers so that program has a form that generates the correct trigger format for things such as "CREATE TRIGGER 'triggername' ...etc. The program users interact with to enter each row is using PHP to send data to MySQL.

```
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO invoices SET invoices.totalquantity=SUM(lineitems.quantity) WHERE invoices.id=lineitems.invoiceid;
    INSERT INTO invoices SET invoices.totalsqft = ((SUM( lineitems.quantity ))*((lineitems.width + lineitmes.widthf)*(lineitems.height+lineitems.heightf))) WHERE invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid;
    INSERT INTO lineitems SET lineitems.unitweight = SUM(layup_config.weight) WHERE layup-config.parentid IN (SELECT lineitems.productid FROM lineitems WHERE lineitems.invoiceid=invoices.id AND lineitems.displayorder=0);
    END
```

I also tried the following code instead of the previous code:

```
    //Inserts new invoice row but not lineitems data
    BEGIN
    SET @totalqty = (SELECT SUM(lineitems.quantity) FROM lineitems INNER  JOIN invoices ON lineitems.invoiceid=invoices.id);
    INSERT INTO invoices SET invoices.NEW.totalquantity = @totalqty;
    END
```

I think the problem I'm encountering is that the section to enter data for the lineitems table is on the same page as the code to save invoices table data. But, both are updated when the same "save" button is clicked. I think I'm trying to update the invoices table before the needed lineitems table actually gets saved.

Ex: invoice data gets entered, invoice trigger runs before lineitems data gets entered but needs to use the lineitems data, so it fails.

I think having the trigger on the lineitems table is the correct way to go, but I can't seem to get the trigger to work correctly in that table...

Please Help!!!!!

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the order of insert the item, and you try to update something isnt there yet.

Comment: I've trouble to really understand what's the process flow. Can you elaborate your paragraph "I think the problem I'm encountering is..."? Also a PHP code sample of the corresponding "skeleton" would be of help.

Comment: cFreed, I actually ended up creating a different question relating to this because i don't think the trigger will work given the previously existing php code from the original programmer. I posted the question to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116029/update-mysql-table-column-using-the-sum-of-a-php-value-stored-in-an-array/40116596?noredirect=1#comment67506542_40116596 . All the php code for the data insertion of these tables is posted in this question. Thank you!!!