# use arrayed checkbox values in php MySQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to send the values of 7 jquery checkboxes to php via ajax. I am attempting to put the values in an array and serialize the array in ajax. Ultimately, I would like to use the values of the checkboxes as conditions in a MySQL WHERE clause. My ajax completes successfully but I'm not sure how to pull the values out of the php variable and use them in the WHERE clause of my MySQL SELECT statement.

Thank you!!!

CODE:

My HTML code:

```
<label for="prestage_select">Prestage</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="prestage_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Prestage">


<label for="validation_select">Validation</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="validation_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Validation"> 


<label for="scheduling_select">Scheduling</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="scheduling_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Scheduling">


<label for="production_select">Production</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="production_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Production">


<label for="needsBOL_select">Needs BOL</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="needsBOL_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Needs BOL">


<label for="shpAcct2Close_select">Shipped: Account to Close</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="shpAcct2Close_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Shipped: Acctg. To Close Out">


<label for="movedToComplete_select">Moved to Complete for Selected Period</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="movedToComplete_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Complete">
```

My Ajax Code:

```
j("#create_submit").click(function(){


     //This works perfectly as long but the dates don't get sent through, causing my WHERE clause to fail unless I remove the $revenuefrom and $revenueto parts of the WHERE clause...

     j.ajax ({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: "revenue_report.php",
                  data: j('#revenue_form').serializeArray(),
                  success: function( response ) {
                      j('#fieldset_ReportDiv').html(response);
                  }
              });


        //No longer works...
            //send Revenue Data values to php using ajax.
                 // var revenuechbxarray = j('.revenuechbxs:checked').serializeArray();
                  var revenuefrom = j('#revenuefrom').val();
                  var revenueto = j('#revenueto').val();

                  j.ajax ({
                      method: 'POST',
                      url: "revenue_report.php",
                      data: { revenuefromtext: revenuefrom, revenuetotext: revenueto },
                  success: function( response ) {
                      j('#fieldset_ReportDiv').html(response);
                  }
                  });



        //   console.log(revenuechbxarray);
```

My PHP Code:

```
<?php

include('inc.php');


//Get date range.

$revenuefromajax=$_POST['revenuefromtext'];
$revenuetoajax=$_POST['revenuetotext'];

$revenuefromstring = strtotime($revenuefromajax);
$revenuetostring = strtotime($revenuetoajax);

$revenuefrom=date("Y-m-d", $revenuefromstring);
$revenueto=date("Y-m-d", $revenuetostring);


//Get selected Status Values.

    if (isset($_POST['revenue_checkboxes'])) {
    $revenue_check = $_POST['revenue_checkboxes'];

    print_r($revenue_check);


    }; //Correctly displays only the values of selected checkboxes.


//connect  to the database 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//echo 'MySQL Connected successfully.'."<BR>";


$conn->select_db("some database name");  /////Database name has been changed for security reasons/////////

if(! $conn->select_db("some database name") ) {
    echo 'Could not select database. '."<BR>";
}

// echo 'Successfully selected database. '."<BR>";

//Select Data and Display it in a table.


$sql = "SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, invoices.stagestatus, FORMAT(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice), 2) AS totalprice, clients.company, lineitems.invoiceid, FORMAT((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144, 2 ) AS sqft, lineitems.quantity AS qty, FORMAT((invoices.totalprice / ((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144)), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice) / lineitems.quantity), 2) AS avgunitrevenue
    FROM clients
    INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.clientid
    INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid
    WHERE invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."' AND invoices.stagestatus IN (' .
    implode(',' array_map(function($revenue_check) {
      return '" . $revenue_check . "';
    })) . '
    )
    ORDER BY invoices.id DESC";


$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
<tr>

<th>Customer</th>
<th>SG</th>
<th>Revenue</th>
<th>SQ FT</th>
<th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
<th>Number of Units</th>
<th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
</tr>";


 if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

     // fetch associative array 
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['sqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     } 

     echo "</table>";

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     //Free the result variable. 
     $result->free();
}

//Close the Database connection.
$conn->close(); 


?>
```

Note: I included the other ajax call for revenueto and revenuefrom date. This call is successful and my table displays correctly based off those dates. I just can't seem the get all actual values for my selected checkboxes from the same page as the dates.

Once I get the values, I'll also take any suggestions for properly using them in my WHERE statement. Each checkbox value matches the a value option invoices.stagestatus.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: you can also look at @rdimouro own answer below, where he shows its complete now working version.

---

As you guessed, with your current code *only the first* checkbox value is added to the data you pass to Ajax.
To simply grasp the whole form data you can merely use `$('form').serialize()`, like demonstrated by this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('form').serialize());
});
```

```css
label, button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Prestage" checked>
    Prestage
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Validation" checked>
    Validation
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Scheduling">
    Scheduling
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Production" checked>Production
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Needs BOL">Needs BOL
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Shipped: Acctg. To Close Out">Shipped: Account to Close
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" value="Complete">Moved to Complete for Selected Period
  </label>
  <label>
    Other data
    <input type="text" name="other-data" value="Some other data">
  </label>
</form>
```

You see that, with this unique statement, you get a pretty complete set of all your data, so you can use it in your Ajax call with nothing more than this:

```
j("#create_submit").click(function(){
    //send Revenue Data values to php using ajax.
    j.ajax ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "revenue_report.php",
        data: j('#yourFormId').serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
            j('#fieldset_ReportDiv').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So in PHP you receive as many `$_POST` items as exist different `name`s in your form. So the `$_POST['revenue_checkboxes']` one will be an array (with *only the checked values*).

BTW PLEASE NOTE: in your current PHP code you're looking for `$_POST['revenuechbx']`, which was correct because it's how you directly named it in the `data{}` argument of the Ajax call. But with the above code you get *the HTML `name` attributes*.

Now regarding how to use the checkboxes values in your WHERE clause, your question is not clear enough to be totally sure.
But if the possible values of the `stagestatus` column in `invoices` are directly the ones cited as `value` attribute in your HTML `<input>`s, then it's pretty simple:

```
$sql = '
SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, invoices.stagestatus, ...
FROM clients
    INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.clientid
    INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid
WHERE invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."'
    AND invoices stagestatus IN (' .
        implode(',', array_map(function($item) {
          return '"' . $item . '"';
        }, $revenue_check)) . '
    )
ORDER BY invoices.id DESC
';
```

Above we use `array_map()` to wrap quotes around each item, then `implode()` to get a comma-separated list, so populating the SQL `IN()` clause.
This way, only the invoices with one of the checked statuses will be selected.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to change my code to bring over all checked chbx values. As for using the value in the MySQL WHERE clause, the value attribute of each checkbox directly matches the value of the invoices column in MySQL so the code example you gave should work just fine. However, I am getting a syntax error in the code but I am not sure what it is. I am able to run through the sql select statement successfully, but the table can't display any data, only the headers. I also know that the array values are successfully sent to php. I will edit the above code for you.

Comment: @rdimouro Glad if ti (at least partially) helps. In the other hand, please post the text and place of the syntax error you got.

Comment: I use dreamweaver for my code editor. It showed a syntax error in the where clause referencing the the line of code in the IN statement after invoices.stagestatus. I was able to remove those errors by putting double quotes in this line of code:

Comment: *** return '" . $revenue_check . "';

Comment: is it correct to replace "item" with $revenu_check" (the variable that holds the arrayed chbx values)?

Comment: @rdimouro Oops! I get it: in the PHP part inside of SQL I wrote all as if it was JS rather than PHP :) So please replace `item` by `$item` in its 2 occurrences.

Comment: So I tried using $item instead but have the same outcome  (table headers display but no data). How does $item "know" to use the values held in $revenue_check?

Comment: @rdimouro Really sorry: again, I wrote partially like if it was JS (where the original data features befores the function, so doesn't appear as argument). In addition, I realize I also forgot a comma between `implode()` arguments! Please look at my edited answer to be sure of the exact correction.

Comment: So I am still unable to display the data. Could I try making this changes before my sql statement and saving it to another variable to I can simply include the variable the way I have with my date variables? Or is the issue related to the values somehow not matching the column values in the MySQL table? I created the checkbox values to exactly mirrow the values uses input when adding a row to the invoices table.

Comment: @rdimouro Now I don't see what can be wrong with the code. So it must be tested: please add an `echo $sql;` and look at the query text. Then, if you don't see anything wrong, directly execute it with phpMyAdmin to see the results.

Comment: lol this is how the echoed $sql query is listed:" ' AND invoices.stagestatus = ('Array,Array,Array') ORDER BY invoices.id DESC" So it taking each value as array instead of the values.

Comment: If this helps, when I print_r() $revenue_check before using it in php, the result I see in the browser is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => revenue_checkboxes[] [value] => Prestage ) [1] => Array ( [name] => revenue_checkboxes[] [value] => Validation ) [2] => Array ( [name] => revenue_checkboxes[] [value] => Scheduling ) ). So does that mean I'm still not bringing the checkboxes from ajax over correcting? Also, I've noticed that I have to wait about 5 seconds between selecting my checkboxes before hitting my create button to submit them to Ajax. Otherwise, my ajax returns empty.

Comment: @rdimouro Again, didn't pay sufficient attention: since you're using POST method, the `data` member of the Ajax call must _not_ be an object, so the correct line is `data: j('#yourFormId').serialize(),` (without brackets). BTW another point: since you're using Ajax you don't want the form actually submitted, so you must add `return false;` at the end of the handler. Look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you!!! Thank you!!! Thank you!!! The one part I was forgetting after serializing the form was that I no longer needed the second ajax call for the dates because they were already being serialized. My table displays perfectly now based off date and status!!!! THANK YOU!!!!!! I will edit the final results so others can reference as needed.

Comment: You were welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer. BTW, I edited mine in order to point yours, which otherwise wouldn't get much attention.

Comment: cFreed, I was wondering if you could take a look at another question i've posted? it has to do with MySQL triggers. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046727/mysql-after-update-and-after-insert-triggers-fail-when-row-is-entered?noredirect=1#comment67369974_40046727

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array through an ajax request. Initialize as an empty array and then push the values of the each selected checkboxes into the array (I've commented your code to show where to do the change):

```
//send Revenue Data values to php using ajax.
//var revenuechbxarray = j('.revenuechbxs:checked').val();
var revenuechbxarray = [];
j('.revenuechbxs:checked').each(function(){
   revenuechbxarray.push(j(this).val());
});
```

I don't know if there's a most elegant way to do it.

When submitting you will see something like this:

`Array ( [0] => Prestage [1] => Validation [2] => Scheduling )`

Note that not checked elements are not posted.

In the PHP side, to check if a checkbox is posted, check if its value is in the array :

```
if (in_array('Prestage', $revenue_check)){
     // your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete answer that worked for my situation. Thank you to cFreed for all the help and edits!!!!!!

MY CODE:

HTML:

```
    <label for="prestage_select">Prestage</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="prestage_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Prestage">


    <label for="validation_select">Validation</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="validation_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Validation"> 


    <label for="scheduling_select">Scheduling</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="scheduling_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Scheduling">


    <label for="production_select">Production</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="production_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Production">


    <label for="needsBOL_select">Needs BOL</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="needsBOL_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Needs BOL">


    <label for="shpAcct2Close_select">Shipped: Account to Close</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="shpAcct2Close_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Shipped: Acctg. To Close Out">


    <label for="movedToComplete_select">Moved to Complete for Selected Period</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="revenue_checkboxes[]" id="movedToComplete_select" class="revenuechbxs" value="Complete">
```

AJAX:

```
          j("#create_submit").click(function(){


            //send Revenue Data values to php using ajax.

               j.ajax ({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: "revenue_report.php",
                  data: j('#revenue_form').serializeArray(),
                  success: function( response ) {
                      j('#fieldset_ReportDiv').html(response);
                  }

               });


            //Remove Criteria selection fields.
            j("#fieldset_2").remove(); 
            j("#fieldset_3").remove();
            j("#fieldset_4").remove();
            j("#fieldset_5").remove();
            j("#fieldset_6").remove();
            j("#fieldset_7").remove();
            j("#createDiv").remove();

            //Show selected tables.
            j("#revenueDT").show();

            j("#revenueReport").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});
            j("#ontimeReport").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});
            j("#rejectReport").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});
            j("#scheduleReport").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});
            j("#customReport").css({"visibility":"visible", "display":"block"});




          });



       return false;
```

PHP:

```
    <?php

    include('inc.php');


    //Get date range.

    $revenuefromajax=$_POST['revenuefrom'];
    $revenuetoajax=$_POST['revenueto'];

    $revenuefromstring = strtotime($revenuefromajax);
    $revenuetostring = strtotime($revenuetoajax);

    $revenuefrom=date("Y-m-d", $revenuefromstring);
    $revenueto=date("Y-m-d", $revenuetostring);




    //Get selected Status Values.

    //$revenuecheckboxes=$_POST['revenuechbx'];
    //echo $revenuecheckboxes;

    //$revenuecheckboxes=var_dump($_POST['revenuechbx']);

    if (isset($_POST['revenue_checkboxes'])) {
    $revenue_check = $_POST['revenue_checkboxes'];


    };






    //connect  to the database 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
      printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    //echo 'MySQL Connected successfully.'."<BR>";


    $conn->select_db("some_DB_name");

     if(! $conn->select_db("some_DB_name") ) {

         echo 'Could not select database. '.'<BR>';
     }

    // echo 'Successfully selected database. '."<BR>";

    //Select Data and Display it in a table.


    $sql = "SELECT invoices.id, invoices.orderdate, invoices.stagestatus, FORMAT(TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice), 2) AS totalprice, clients.company, lineitems.invoiceid, FORMAT((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144, 2 ) AS sqft, lineitems.quantity AS qty, FORMAT((invoices.totalprice / ((lineitems.width * lineitems.height) /144)), 2) as avgsqftrevenue, FORMAT((TRIM(LEADING '$' FROM invoices.totalprice) / lineitems.quantity), 2) AS avgunitrevenue
    FROM clients
    INNER JOIN invoices ON clients.id = invoices.clientid
    INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id = lineitems.invoiceid
    WHERE invoices.orderdate BETWEEN '".$revenuefrom."' AND '".$revenueto."' AND invoices.stagestatus IN (". implode(',', array_map(function($item) {return '"' . $item . '"'; }, $revenue_check)) .")
    ORDER BY invoices.id DESC";







    //Display daterange and table.
    echo 'Displaying results for: '.$revenuefrom.' to '.$revenueto.'. '.'<BR><BR><BR>';

    $result = $conn->query($sql);



    echo "<table id='revenueReportA' align='center' class='report_DT'>
    <tr>

    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Stage Status</th>
    <th>SG</th>
    <th>Revenue</th>
    <th>SQ FT</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per SQ FT</th>
    <th>Number of Units</th>
    <th>AVG Revenue Per Unit</th>
    </tr>";


     if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        // fetch associative array 
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['company'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['stagestatus'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."$". $row['totalprice'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['sqft'] ."&nbsp;&nbsp;". "ft<sup>2</sup>". "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgsqftrevenue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."$". $row['avgunitrevenue'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        } 

        echo "</table>";


     //Free the result variable. 
     $result->free();

     }


    //Close the Database connection.
    $conn->close(); 



    ?>
```