# Update MySQL table column using the sum of a php value stored in an array

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have an html form that users input data into that saves the values in two MySQL tables, invoices and lineitems. When the "save" button is clicked, these values are inserted as a new row in invoices and lineitems. The page refreshes to display the same form, but with the user-inputted values saved in the input fields. The webpage has multiply 'lineitems' the user can create. This data gets saved to the lineitems table. Each invoice row has a unique id that gets added to each lineitem the user creates. That way the invoice can get each lineitem associated with it from the lineitems table. I need to perform a sum calculation on lineitems.quantity for each invoice and save the value to invoices.totalquantity.

I have tried setting up triggers on the lineitems table itself, but it always fails. I am now trying to do it from the program side.

MY CODE:

```
// LINE ITEMS CLASS 
  // ==============================================================================================
class lineitems{

    var $queryresult = NULL;

    function lineitems($db, $invoiceid, $invoicetype = "Order"){

        $this->db = $db;
        $this->invoiceid = ((int) $invoiceid);
        $this->invoicetype = $invoicetype;

    }//end method


    function get(){

    $querystatement = "
            SELECT
                products.partname,
                products.partnumber,
                products.claveid,
                products.claveid2,
                products.layupid,

                lineitems.id,
                lineitems.productid,

                lineitems.quantity,




                lineitems.nipple,
                lineitems.polish,
                lineitems.edgeseal,
                lineitems.leads,

                lineitems.leadsl,

                lineitems.width,
                lineitems.widthf,
                lineitems.height,
                lineitems.heightf,
                lineitems.comment



            FROM
                lineitems LEFT JOIN products ON lineitems.productid = products.id
            WHERE
                invoiceid = ".$this->invoiceid." 
            ORDER BY
                lineitems.displayorder";



            /*  
            FROM
                lineitems LEFT JOIN products ON lineitems.productid = products.id
            WHERE
                invoiceid = ".$this->invoiceid."
            ORDER BY
                lineitems.displayorder"; */

        $this->queryresult = $this->db->query($querystatement);

}//end method


    function show(){



        if($this->queryresult === NULL)
            $this->get();

        $count = 1;
        while($therecord = $this->db->fetchArray($this->queryresult)){



            ?><tr id="li<?php echo $count?>" class="lineitems">

                <td colspan="2" class="lineitemsLeft" <?php if($this->invoicetype == "Void" || $this->invoicetype == "Invoice") echo 'nowrap="nowrap"'?>>
                    <input type="hidden" id="li<?php echo $count?>ProductID" value="<?php echo $therecord["productid"]?>"/>

                    <div>
                        <?php if($therecord["partnumber"] || $therecord["partname"] ) {?>
                        <p><?php echo formatVariable($therecord["partnumber"]) ?></p>
        <!--                <p class="important"><?//php echo formatVariable($therecord["partname"])?></p> -->

                        <?php } else
                                echo "&nbsp;";
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </td>



    <!--            <td><input id="li<?//php echo $count?>Memo" class="lineitemMemos" value="<?//php echo formatVariable($therecord["memo"])?>"/></td> -->
            <!--    <td><input id="li<?////php echo $count?>Frontfinish" class="lineitemFrontfinishs" value="<?/////php echo formatVariable($therecord["frontfinish"])?>"/></td>
                <td><input id="li<?////php echo $count?>Backfinish" class="lineitemBackfinishs" value="<?////php echo formatVariable($therecord["backfinish"])?>"/></td> -->
                   <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Comment" class="lineitemComments" value="<?php echo formatVariable($therecord["comment"])?>"/></td>

                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Nipple" class="lineitemNipples" value="<?php echo formatVariable($therecord["nipple"])?>"/></td>



                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Polish" class="lineitemPolishes" value="<?php echo formatVariable($therecord["polish"])?>"/></td>




                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Edgeseal" class="lineitemEdgeseals" value="<?php echo formatVariable($therecord["edgeseal"])?>"/></td>

                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Leads" class="lineitemLeadss" value="<?php echo $therecord["leads"]?>"/></td>



                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Leadsl" class="lineitemLeadsls" value="<?php echo $therecord["leadsl"]?>"/></td>
                 <!--    <td><input id="li<?///php echo $count?>RQ" class="lineitemRQs" value="<?///php echo $therecord["RQ"]?>"/></td> -->



                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Width" class="lineitemWidths" value="<?php echo $therecord["width"]?>"/></td>
                 <td>    <input id="li<?php echo $count?>Widthf" class="lineitemWidthfs" value="<?php echo $therecord["widthf"]?>"/></td>

                     <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Height" class="lineitemHeights" value="<?php echo $therecord["height"]?>"/>  </td>
                     <td> <input id="li<?php echo $count?>Heightf" class="lineitemHeightfs" value="<?php echo $therecord["heightf"]?>"/></td>
                     <!--
                                             <td><input id="li<?///php echo $count?>Claveid" class="uneditable lineitemClaveids" value="<?////php echo formatVariable($therecord["claveid"])?>"/></td>

                     <td><input id="li<?////php echo $count?>Claveid2" class="uneditable lineitemClaveid2s" value="<?/////php echo formatVariable($therecord["claveid2"])?>"/></td>

    -->
                <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Quantity" class="lineitemQuantities" value="<?php echo formatVariable($therecord["quantity"])?>"/></td>

       <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Sqft" class="uneditable lineitemSqfts" value="<?php echo formatVariable(ceil($therecord["width"]*$therecord["height"]/144)) ?>"/></td>


       <td><input id="li<?php echo $count?>Sqfttot" class="uneditable lineitemSqfttots" value="<?php echo formatVariable (ceil($therecord["width"]*$therecord["height"]/144* $therecord["quantity"]))?>"/></td> 


      <!--    <td><input id="li<?///php echo $count?>unitweight" class=" uneditable lineitemUnitweight" value="<?///php echo $unitweight ?>"/></td> -->

       <!--    <td><input id="li<?///php echo $count?>totalweight" class="uneditable lineitemTotalweight" value="<?///php echo $totalweight ?>"/></td>   -->                    







                <td class="lineitemsButtonTDs">
                    <div id="li<?php echo $count?>ButtonsDiv" class="lineitemsButtonDivs">
                        <button type="button" id="li<?php echo $count?>ButtonDelete" class="graphicButtons buttonMinus LIDelButtons" title="Remove line item"><span>-</span></button><br />
                        <button type="button" id="li<?php echo $count?>ButtonMoveUp" class="graphicButtons buttonUp LIUpButtons" title="Move Item Up"><span>Up</span></button><br />
                        <button type="button" id="li<?php echo $count?>ButtonMoveDown" class="graphicButtons buttonDown LIDnButtons" title="Move Item Down"><span>Dn</span></button><br />
                    </div>                      
                </td>

            </tr>


            <?php

            $count++;

        }//endwhile

    }//end method


    function set($itemlist, $userid = NULL){

        if(!$userid)
            $userid = $_SESSION["userinfo"]["id"];

        $deletestatement = "
            DELETE FROM
                lineitems
            WHERE
                invoiceid = ".$this->invoiceid;

        $this->db->query($deletestatement);

        $itemsArray = explode(";;", $itemlist);

        $count = 0;

        foreach($itemsArray as $item){

            $itemRecord = explode("::", $item);
            if(count($itemRecord) > 1){

                $insertstatement ="
                    INSERT INTO
                        lineitems(
                            invoiceid, 
                            productid, 
                            comment,
                            nipple,
                            polish,
                            edgeseal,
                            leads,
                            leadsl,
                            width,
                            widthf,
                            height,
                            heightf,
                            quantity,
                            sqft,
                            sqfttot,
                            displayorder,
                            createdby,
                            creationdate,
                            modifiedby,
                            modifieddate
                        )
                    VALUES (
                        ".$this->invoiceid.",
                        ".((int) $itemRecord[0]).",
                        '".$itemRecord[1]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[2]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[3]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[4]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[5]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[6]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[7]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[8]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[9]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[10]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[11]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[12]."',
                        '".$itemRecord[13]."',
                        ".$count.",
                        ".$userid.",
                        NOW(),
                        ".$userid.",
                        NOW()

                    )";

                $this->db->query($insertstatement);


                $count++;

            }//end if

        }//endforeach                       

    }//end method


    //this isn't actually updating my invoices table...
    function updatesglitots() {

        $sglitotalsupdate="UPDATE invoices i LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceid, SUM(quantity) AS sgtotqty FROM lineitems li GROUP BY invoiceid) AS t ON i.invoiceid = t.invoiceid SET i.totalquantity = t.sgtotqty WHERE i.invoiceid = ".$this->invoiceid."";


    $this->db->query($sglitotalsupdate);


    }

}//end class

}// end if
```

I want to do either something like this:

```
    "UPDATE invoices
        SET totalquantity = SUM('".$itemRecord[11]."')
        WHERE invoices.id = ".$this->invoiceid."
    ;"
```

NOTE: '".$itemRecord[11]."' is the array value that holds the quantity for each lineitem a user creates.

OR...

```
     "UPDATE invoices INNER JOIN lineitems
         ON invoices.id=lineitems.invoiceid
         SET invoices.totalquantity = SUM(lineitems.quantity)
         WHERE invoices.id=lineitems.invoiceid
      ;"
```

Please help as I have tried several different methods...

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery, or join the invoices table to a derived table. After you have inserted all the line items, this will calculate the total.

```
"UPDATE invoices i 
SET totalquantity = (
    SELECT SUM(quantity) 
    FROM lineitems li 
    WHERE li.invoiceid = i.invoiceid)
WHERE i.invoiceid = " . $this->invoiceid;

// or

"UPDATE invoices i 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT invoiceid, SUM(quantity) AS total 
    FROM lineitems li 
    GROUP BY invoiceid) AS t
ON i.invoiceid = t.invoiceid
SET i.totalquantity = t.total
WHERE i.invoiceid = " . $this->invoiceid;
```

---

`i`, `li`, and `t` are aliases for the `invoices` table, `lineitems` table, and the derived table in the second query, respectively.

Comment: can you tell me what the "i", "li" and "t" represent? I'm guessing that they are the names of the derived tables? will this updated the column in invoices that I need?

Comment: I updated the answer to explain those abbreviations. Either of these queries should update the correct column in the invoices table.

Comment: So I've edited my question to reflect the code I've added based off your suggestion but I'm not fully sure how to implement it so my invoices table actually updates...

Comment: What type is your invoiceid column? If it isn't INT it will need to be in quotes.

Comment: its INT(11) where 11 is the max length of the integer.

Comment: Did you call the method where that query is executed after inserting all the line items?

Comment: I think so but I'm not sure. Can you give an example of calling the method?

Comment: So I just tried to call the method right after the code creating the method. When I go to test the webpage, it returns a blank screen with no errors when I inspect it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried breaking the code out of the method but nothing I do gets the update to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine the `sum` function from `mysql` with the `array` type from php.

You can use the `array_sum` function from php on the `array` from `php`.

```
"UPDATE invoices
    SET totalquantity = '". array_sum($itemRecord[11]) ."'
    WHERE invoices.id = ".$this->invoiceid."
;"
```

Comment: Are you sure about the second version? I've never seen that use of the `SUM()` function in MySQL. AFAIK, it can only be used as an aggregation function.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks! I was sure I used it before... my bad. SUM is for aggregations. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. It just occurred to me now that using the array value would still only give me the one value for that row. I need to sum up all rows associated with the invoice. I think I would have to use "UPDATE invoices INNER JOIN lineitems ON invoices.id=lineitems.invoiceid
         SET invoices.totalquantity = SUM(lineitems.quantity)
         WHERE invoices.id=lineitems.invoiceid ;" . Or something similar to that. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement that?

Comment: Well, thats a different question... But if you need to set the value of based on other rows - you should probably use a JOIN here.